# OpenCV-Face Detection Debug Assertion Failes

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using this code for face detection in OpenCV . When run, the program works well and detects my face for a second and after that I see this error

[image: Picture of Error]

Here's my code:

```
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\contrib\contrib.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2\objdetect\objdetect.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
    face_cascade.load("haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml");
    VideoCapture captureDevice;
    captureDevice.open(0);
    Mat captureFrame;
    Mat grayscaleFrame;
    namedWindow("outputCapture", 1);
    while (true)
    {
        captureDevice >> captureFrame;
        cvtColor(captureFrame, grayscaleFrame, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        equalizeHist(grayscaleFrame, grayscaleFrame);
        std::vector<Rect> faces;
        face_cascade.detectMultiScale(grayscaleFrame, faces, 1.1, 3
            , CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT | CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30));
        for (int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
        {
            Point pt1(faces[i].x + faces[i].width, faces[i].y + faces[i].height);
            Point pt2(faces[i].x, faces[i].y);
            rectangle(captureFrame, pt1, pt2, cvScalar(0, 255, 0, 0), 1, 8, 0);
        }
        imshow("outputCapture", captureFrame);
        waitKey(33);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What should i do?

Comment: When I tried to click the link for to your Error, my anti virus program blocked the website.

Comment: i change it !!! check it again ... tnx @FrancisCugler

Comment: Please specify version of compiler and OpenCV version. I tried to run this code and it works perfectly. Have you tried to build and run `facedetect` [sample](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/facedetect.cpp)?

Comment: VS 2013 And OpenCV 2.4.4 @akarsakov